# Hiding copy/paste/return panel in iOS 9 (Shortcuts panel)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios9

I'am testing my application on iOS 9 Beta. Apple added a new panel with copy/paste/return functions.

I know I can disable it in general settings of my device.

Can I detect it in code using notifications? And can I tell my textFields and textViews don't show it when they are editing?

If I turn off the predictive view, the panel will display.

I've not found it in xCode 7 beta 4. If you know how to fix this issue please let me know it too :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solve the issue. I've found the way to hide this Shortcuts bar programmatically:

```
if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(inputAssistantItem)])
{
    UITextInputAssistantItem *inputAssistantItem = [textView inputAssistantItem];
    inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
    inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
}
```

Also you can detect the iOS Version if you need.
Important to know UITextInputAssistantItem class is new class for iOS 9.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue] > 8.99)
{
    // Your super-code
}
```

Hope it will be useful information!

Comment: I have not find any solutions for this issue after release version of iOS 9 was dropped. I think it is the best solution to hide Shortcuts Bar now.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on a global level throughout the app so it does not have to be done on EVERY text field....?

Comment: @CommaToast hi. For now I did not find any other solutions for this issue. I think the best way to do it now is to create a TextFieldDecoratorClass which will be adding this option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
        return NO;
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for my situation :(